# Issues with setting up a Azure python function app on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm having trouble setting up an Azure Python Function App that I cloned from a repository on my local machine. When I set up the virtual environment and hit debug to run the Function App as an endpoint I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt <

/usr/bin/bash: .venvScriptspython: command not found
The terminal process "C:\Users\jgarcia\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe '-c', '.venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt'" terminated with exit code: 127.
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Edit 1: I'm running this by clicking on debug in VS Code

Edit 2: I copied and pasted the command in terminal, and I got the exact same error, however when I run the command like this:

```
.venv/Scripts/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It works. So it seems as though the problem is in running debug in VS code. How would I fix that?

Edit 3: I found a way to work around VS Code's debug by typing in the following in the command line:

```
func host start
```

Though I still don't know why running debug in VS Code runs the wrong command. Might have something to do with using Bash vs. PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you could try to run it with slashes instead of backslashes:

`.venv/Scripts/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I'm running this by clicking on debug in VS code, I'm not typing any commands in the terminal

Comment: can you link the repo?

Comment: is there a special plugin for that in vscode?

Comment: Sorry I can't link the repo

Comment: And yes there is a debug feature in VS code for Azure Function App that i'm using. Right now though I'm running it by typing everything in the command line because running with debug uses backslashes. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a task, because of the error message prompt: `Executing task`.

Then the path of the command: `.venv\Scripts\python` has been changed to the command: `.venvScriptspython`. When are using `.venv/Scripts/python`, it works well. So, you need to change the `backslash` to `slash` in the `tasks.json` file.